# Which constructor will trigger the move semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm currently learning c++ and is wondering about the which one is the right way to use std::move

```
//Code might be incorrect since I havent tested it out
Xyt::ByteArray* Xyt::ResourceManager::LoadFileToByteArray(std::string Path)
{
try {
    std::ifstream FileStream(Path, std::ios::in);
    std::ifstream::pos_type Pos = FileStream.tellg();

    FileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<char> Buff(Pos);
    FileStream.read(Buff.data(), Pos);

    FileStream.close();

    //I want to trigger the move constructor here
    return new Xyt::ByteArray(std::move(Buff));
}
catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "ERROR::FILE::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << Path << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
    }
}
```

What I'm confused about is which one will trigger the move constructor for std::vector ?

Is it this one (compile error when caller doesnt use std::move)

```
Xyt::ByteArray::ByteArray(std::vector<char>&& Buffer)
{
    this->Buffer = Buffer;
}
```

this one (accepts both std::move(Buff) and Buff) ?

```
Xyt::ByteArray::ByteArray(std::vector<char> Buffer)
{
    this->Buffer = Buffer;
}
```

or this one ?

```
Xyt::ByteArray::ByteArray(std::vector<char> Buffer)
{
    this->Buffer = std::move(Buffer);
}
```

My understanding from reading around the internet, that the 1st constructor is the correct way to utilize the move semantics. But if I use the 1st constructor does that mean I need to make another constructor if I want to actually do a copy on the std::vector Buff ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one that works is the third. But that's because you used `std::move` *inside* the constructor. And it provokes two moves: one to fill in the parameter, and one from the parameter into the value.

The correct way to do this is:

```
Xyt::ByteArray::ByteArray(std::vector<char>&& Buf)
  : Buffer(std::move(Buf))
{}
```

This only invokes the move operation once.

You have to explicitly move from named rvalue references if you want to invoke a move operation.

---

> But if I use the 1st constructor does that mean I need to make another constructor if I want to actually do a copy on the std::vector Buff ?

You don't strictly have to. You could require users to do the copying themselves when they call the function:

```
Xyt::ByteArray(std::vector<char>(Buff))
```

But yes, if you want users to provide an lvalue directly, and you want to copy from the lvalue, then you need to provide a constructor that takes a (`const`) lvalue reference and performs a copy.

Comment: I think I get it. One more thing though,
Xyt::ByteArray::ByteArray(std::vector<char>&& Buffer)
    {
        this->Buffer = std::move(Buffer);
    }, If do a std::move like this, would this invoke the move constructor twice similiar to the third constructor ?

Comment: @Xyten: No. It won't invoke the move *constructor* at all. It will invoke move *assignment*, since `ByteArray::Buffer` is a *live object* at that point. That's why I used the member initializer; that's where you put *initialization* of members.